# Spanish Version before the English version in the Help Center

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, estado-completado

Should be possible put the Spanish version before the English version in the [Help Center](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea. This is done now, along with a couple other minor tweaks.